# Upsample each pandas dateindex row including previous dates within group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data looks something like this:

```
ID1  ID2 Date        Values 
1    1   2018-01-05  75
1    1   2018-01-06  83
1    1   2018-01-07  17
1    1   2018-01-08  15
1    2   2018-02-01  85
1    2   2018-02-02  98
2    1   2018-02-15  54
2    1   2018-02-16  17
2    1   2018-02-17  83
2    1   2018-02-18  94
2    2   2017-12-18  16
2    2   2017-12-19  84
2    2   2017-12-20  47
2    2   2017-12-21  28
2    2   2017-12-22  38
```

**All the operations must be done within groups of `['ID1', 'ID2']`.**
What I want to do is upsample the dataframe in a way such that I end up with a sub-dataframe for each `'Date'` index which includes all previous dates including the current one from it's own `['ID1', 'ID2']` group. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
ID1  ID2 DateGroup   Date           Values 
1    1   2018-01-05  2018-01-05     75
1    1   2018-01-06  2018-01-05     75
1    1   2018-01-06  2018-01-06     83
1    1   2018-01-07  2018-01-05     75
1    1   2018-01-07  2018-01-06     83
1    1   2018-01-07  2018-01-07     17
1    1   2018-01-08  2018-01-05     75
1    1   2018-01-08  2018-01-06     83
1    1   2018-01-08  2018-01-07     17
1    1   2018-01-08  2018-01-08     15
1    2   2018-02-01  2018-02-01     85
1    2   2018-02-02  2018-02-01     85
1    2   2018-02-02  2018-02-02     98
2    1   2018-02-15  2018-02-15     54
2    1   2018-02-16  2018-02-15     54
2    1   2018-02-16  2018-02-16     17
2    1   2018-02-17  2018-02-15     54
2    1   2018-02-17  2018-02-16     17
2    1   2018-02-17  2018-02-17     83
2    1   2018-02-18  2018-02-15     54
2    1   2018-02-18  2018-02-16     17
2    1   2018-02-18  2018-02-17     83
2    1   2018-02-18  2018-02-18     94
2    2   2017-12-18  2017-12-18     16
2    2   2017-12-19  2017-12-18     16
2    2   2017-12-19  2017-12-19     84
2    2   2017-12-20  2017-12-18     16
2    2   2017-12-20  2017-12-19     84
2    2   2017-12-20  2017-12-20     47
2    2   2017-12-21  2017-12-18     16
2    2   2017-12-21  2017-12-19     84
2    2   2017-12-21  2017-12-20     47
2    2   2017-12-21  2017-12-21     28
2    2   2017-12-22  2017-12-18     16
2    2   2017-12-22  2017-12-19     84
2    2   2017-12-22  2017-12-20     47
2    2   2017-12-22  2017-12-21     28
2    2   2017-12-22  2017-12-22     38
```

The dataframe I'm working with is quite big (~20 million rows), thus I would like to avoid iterating through each row.

Is it possible to use a function or combination of pandas functions like resample/apply/reindex to achieve what I need?

Comment: Do you mean "all previous dates in the same calendar month..."?

Comment: No, I mean including all available previous dates for a particular group, i.e. `['ID1', 'ID2']` .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ID1 and ID2 is your original Index. You should reset the index, set Date as Index, reset the index back to [ID1, ID2]:

```
 df = df.reset_index().set_index(['Date']).resample('d').ffill().reset_index().set_index(['ID1','ID2'])
```

If your 'Date' field is string, then you should be converting it into datetime before resampling on that field. You can use the below for that:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: I don't understand how that would solve the problem. Resetting the index will remove the groups of `['ID1', 'ID2']`.

Comment: But I am putting the index back after resampling.

Comment: I think you did not understand the problem. Dropping the grouping and then resampling would create additional dates between the groups and that is wrong.